# TypeScript/Angular2: Find all occurrences of an image path in a string, insert an alternative path before the filename

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm developing a module in Angular2 to display static html placed in the same folder as its resources (images and stylesheets). The paths in the html are relative, which means when the html is loaded into my Angular component the links break.

If I were using Angular 1x I probably would have been able to use ng-include to inject the html into a container, correct me if I'm wrong. I've gone ahead to create a pipe to find all instances of images in the html and change its path:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'resourcePath' })

export class ResourcePathPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(html: string, folder: string): any {
        if (!html) return html;

        let search = 'src="',
            filtered = html.substr(0, html.indexOf(search)),
            replacement = 'src="http://' + window.location.host + '/files/uploads/parentFolder/' + folder + '/';

        for (let index = html.indexOf(search); index >= 0; index = html.indexOf(search, index + 1)) {
            let chunk = html.substr(index, html.indexOf(search, index + 1));

            if (chunk.length > 0) {
                filtered += replacement + chunk.substr(5);
            } else {
                let end = html.substr(html.lastIndexOf(search) + replacement.length, html.length);
                filtered += end;
                console.log("Completed!");
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

I'm getting very inconsistent results, sometimes with the `src` attribute completely missing. If anyone knows a better approach to achieving this I would appreciate the insight.

**UPDATE**
Here's a snippet of HTML I've passed through the pipe to test:

```
<div id="pf1" class="pf w0 h0" data-page-no="1"><div class="pc pc1 w0 h0"><img class="bi x0 y0 w1 h1" alt="" src="bg1.png"/></div><div class="pi" data-data='{"ctm":[1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000]}'></div></div>
```

Comment: Would be great if you include some examples of inputs and also parameters for this `pipe` and their expected behavior.

Comment: Hello @developer033, I've just added a snippet of HTML to my post.